# Symfony3 Serializer - How to separate values from dot strings and combine in one array column

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

I get data from http request in given form

```
{
  "start_date": "2017-03-13",
  "end_date": "2017-03-19",
  "visitors_total": 2555,
  "views_total": 2553,
  "visitors_country.france": 100,
  "visitors_country.germany": 532,
  "visitors_country.poland": 32,
  "views_country.france": 110,
  "views_country.germany": 821,
  "views_country.poland": 312,
}
```

doctrine entity defination for columns

```
"start_date" => datetime
"end_date" => datetime
"visitors_total" => int
"views_total" => int
"visitors_country" => array
"views_country => array
```

For the visitors_country and views_country , array keys/values are separated by dots. These dot separated values

```
"views_country.france": 110,
"views_country.germany": 821,
"views_country.poland": 312,
```

shoud be

```
'view_country' => array(
   'france'=> 110,
   'germany'=> 821,
   'poland'=> 312,
);
```

I am using Symfony serialize component for the serialization of requested data and having problem to denormalize the data.

I did something like this

```
class ArrayDotNormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *

     */
    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
     // Actually, this function applies to each column of requested data ,
    //but how to  separate values by dot and join them in one array and store as array json in db ?
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {

        return strpos($data, '.') !== false;
    }

}
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Data from http is json? if so then decode json will return array and then try using explode option with (dot) to make as your desired array structure

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
class ArrayDotNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setAttributeValue($object, $attribute, $value, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if (strpos($attribute, '.') !== false) {
            list($attribute, $country) = explode('.', $attribute);
            $currentValue = (array) $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($object, $attribute);
            $value = array_replace($currentValue, [$country => $value]);
        }

        return parent::setAttributeValue($object, $attribute, $value, $format, $context);
    }
}
```

and use this normalizer in your serializer:

```
 $serializer = new Serializer([new ArrayDotNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]);
```

Result:

[image]